# MySQL Workbench reports an error Code: 1064 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, Freight 
FROM orders 
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM WHERE City in ('Germany', 'Mexico', 'Spain')) 
ORDER BY Freight DESC;
```

[image: workbench code]

Comment: Use a subquery to find the orders that were placed by customers in the countries of Germany,
Mexico or Spain. Display the OrderID, OrderDate (excluding the time) and Freight sorted by
Freight in descending order.

Comment: Shouldn't there be the table name between `FROM` and `WHERE` in the subquery

Answer (score 0):

Your inner SELECT clause has a from with out a table.

I added **orders2** as tablename because i don't know exactly what you have in mind

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, Freight 
FROM orders 
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM orders2 WHERE City in ('Germany', 'Mexico', 'Spain')) 
ORDER BY Freight DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear but if only one table is involved, I think this is a simple form.

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, Freight 
FROM orders 
WHERE  City IN ('Germany', 'Mexico', 'Spain')) 
ORDER BY Freight DESC;
```

or if there are two tables

```
SELECT a.OrderID, a.OrderDate, a.Freight 
FROM orders a, orders2 b
WHERE a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID AND b.city IN ('Germany', 'Mexico', 'Spain')) 
ORDER BY a.Freight DESC;
```

A join may also be used.